# Find Equation of line to solve a cubic function

Tags: graphing-functions, cubics

A cubic graph for $x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x - 4$ is given.

Question is: Find an equation of the line you would draw on that graph to solve graphically: $x^3 + 4x^2 + 3x - 1 = 0.$

Give the answer in $y = mx + c$ form.

Comment: You are looking for a line that will intersect the first cubic in the same points as the second cubic does.  You can then read off the intersection points from the graph.  The two cubics look very similar, don't they?

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange community. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site  will help you get the most of your time here.

Comment: @RossMillikan, The cubics are indeed similar. The point of intersection of both cubics is at (-3,-1). Should I be finding an equation of a tangent on the second cubic at (-3,-1).

Also, they are asking to solve that cubic graphically through the equation of that line. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^3 + 4x^2 + 3x - 1 = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $x^3 + 4x^2 + 2x - 4 =-x-3 $

Then answer is $y=-x-3$. 
[image]

Solutions of $x^3 + 4x^2 + 3x - 1 = 0$ is intersection points
$$x\approx0.247,\quad x\approx-1.445,\quad x\approx-2.802$$